# Cannot reach localhost from angular application configured inside nginx

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ubuntu, nginx, web-deployment

I have an application developed by angular as frontend and spring boot for the backend.

I deployed them in `Nginx` running in `Ubuntu` server including let's encrypt ssl certificates

The front end is deployed in the following path `/var/www/my-app-domain.local`
The backend is a jar which is running on port 8080

The `Nginx` configuration is in following file located in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/my-app-domain.local.conf`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name my-app-domain;

        location /api/ {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
}

server {
    server_name my-app-domain www.my-app-domain; # managed by Certbot
    index index.html;
    root /var/www/my-app-domain.local;
    location / {
        #        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-app-domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-app-domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}server {
    if ($host = my-app-domain) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = my-app-domain) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    server_name my-app-domain www.my-app-domain;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

When I call the domain name in the browser, it rejected the call for the API from the webapp 
showing this error in the console : **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** for calling  http://localhost:8080/api/*****

However, when I call the same API from the browser, it's calling successfully without any issues.

Is my Ngnix configuration incorrect? what should I do with this error and what is the proper way for calling APIs in production environment?

Comment: what url is your Angular set up to talk to?

Comment: @timur I didn't get your question, I already posted the configuration `www.my-app-domain`

Comment: i see `nginx` config file - this is server side, right? you mention however there's an Angular app that's actually failing and throwing an error - so I'm trying to see how the app is configured - it's probably another config somewhere, unless I'm missing it in your file?

Comment: I generated a `dist` folder and paste it in the following path `/var/www/my-app-domain.local` which is mentioned in the config file

Comment: i'm still not sure i understand how your client side is configured. do you mind posting a screenshot or your browser network tab when the angular app errors out?

Comment: Check if port `8080` is in use by another app or service (`netstat -tulnp`). Make sure that the server is up and running on port `8080`. I'd suggest changing that port to something else, maybe `1000x`. Last but not least, have a look at ["Proxying to a backend server"](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server).

Comment: is the page visible in `localhost:8080`?

Comment: whereever you make the API call in your angular frontend code, you probably talk with the wrong URL. Instead of talking to http://localhost:8080/api/ you need to use http://my-app-domain/api/ otherwise the angular app tries to connect to your local computer, which probably does not listen on this port. Can you show the _frontend_ code of your app as well?

Comment: Did you try 127.0.0.1? maybe it is a DNS issue

Comment: @ChristosLytras The port 8080 is used by spring boot app

Comment: @user1511208 yes, that is obvious. I'm just telling you to check if there is another app using that port. For example on my server ISPConfig is using that port. There may be some other service using it that's why I suggest you try and switch to another port and see if it's working.

Comment: @ChristosLytras It's used by java which is the spring boot app

Comment: @midrizi I tried to curl `localhost:8080` and `curl 127.0.0.1:8080`  from terminal and gave me error  `{"timestamp":"2020-04-02T19:46:12.259+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/"}`

Comment: here is my proxy.conf.json 
`{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false
    }
  }`